# Aws get entitlement issue host not resolved

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I have issue with aws php sdk that the getentitlments has host not resolve

AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: entitlement.marketplace.us-east-2.amazonaws.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'

Comment: Are you sure that is the endpoint? whatsmydns.net and dig are returning nothing for that DNS entry. https://dnslookup.org/#/127.0.0.1/entitlement.marketplace.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/A  https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/entitlement.marketplace.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: yes, This address has been generated by Aws\MarketplaceEntitlementService\MarketplaceEntitlementServiceClient
,I know as address is unreachable ,I want to know why this error occuring.

Comment: Try setting the region to us-east-1 in the client.